# Como puedo hacer casting explicitamente en una imagen? C#

Tags: c#, imagen, net

A traves de una API esta me devuelve una imagen (supuestamente), asique generé una lista con todas las imagenes que necesitaba para castearlas en unos pictureBox, sin emargo, obtengo el siguiente error:

> No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo
>   'RiotSharp.StaticDataEndPoint.ImageStatic' en 'system.Drawing.Image'

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Éste es el código:

```
for(int j = 0; j < ImagenHechizos.Count(); j++)
{
    ImagenHechizos[j].Image = SharkiQuerys.Hechizos[j].Image;
}
```

¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

Comment: Los errores deben ir en el cuerpo de la pregunta y no como imagenes. Por favor corrige eso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según la [documentación de RiotSharp](http://benfradet.github.io/RiotSharp/api/RiotSharp.StaticDataEndpoint.ImageStatic.html#RiotSharp_StaticDataEndpoint_ImageStatic), `ImageStatic` no es una clase que se contenga a la imagen, sino que representa a la imagen.

Se menciona que la clase `ImageStatic` tiene las siguientes propiedades (o atributos):

- **Full**: *Full name for this image.* `System.String`
- **Group** *Image's group (spell, champion, item, etc).* `System.String`
- **Height**: *Image's height.* `System.Int32`
- **Sprite**: *Image's sprite.* `System.String`
- **Width**: *Image's width.* `System.Int32`
- **X**: *X starting point for this image.* `System.Int32`
- **Y**: *Y starting point for this image.* `System.Int32`

Por lo tanto asumo que en `Full` se debe encontrar el nombre de la imagen que quieres obtener, mas no la imagen en sí; para obtener la imagen posiblemente tengas que traerla desde una *url* concatenando el nombre de la imagen. Algo así:

```
for(int j = 0; j < ImagenHechizos.Count(); j++)
{
    String imageURL = "http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/img/spell/"
                      + SharkiQuerys.Hechizos[j].Image.Full;

    ImagenHechizos[j].ImageLocation = imageURL;
}
```

Por ejemplo esta sería una de las imágenes a obtener:
http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/img/spell/SummonerFlash.png

*Si te surge alguna duda relacionada con la API de RiotGames puedes también preguntar en su propio foro: [RiotGames Developers](https://discussion.developer.riotgames.com/index.html)*

Comment: La traia con la propiedad Key que tenia la lista de propiedades de en este caso Hechizos[j], sin embargo no estaba muy seguro si era la forma adecuada (String de ruta + el string traido por key), ya que pensaba que era una mala practica al ver que existia una propiedad llamada Image, (Pensando que ésta, sería la imagen en sí). Veo entonces, que lo habia hecho estaba medianamente bien, aunque con full me evito concatenar el .png. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta :)

Answer (score 1):

Buenas tardes amigo sería así:

```
for(int j = 0; j < ImagenHechizos.Count(); j++)
 {
       ImagenHechizos[j].Image = (System.Drawing.Image)SharkiQuerys.Hechizos[j].Image;
 }
```

Pero eso no asegura que verdaderamente herede de esa clase.

Comment: Buenas :) Lo primero que pensé es que el casting se haría así, pero sigue sin dejarme... Hasta el punto en el que, el propio visual studio me dice que la conversión es innecesaria y me aconseja quitarla. ¿No hay alguna otra forma de cargar esa imagen?

Comment: Si hereda de la clase Image? Leí la documentación y no consigo donde se herede de Image: https://benfradet.github.io/RiotSharp/api/RiotSharp.StaticDataEndpoint.ImageStatic.html

Comment: Pues, sinceramente no tengo ni idea, puse la propiedad Image porque di por hecho que se necesitaba esa propiedad para llamar a la imagen que generase, ya que ImageLocation es para strings rutas y demás... ¿Si no fuese con la propiedad Image, con que propiedad seria? Gracias :)

Comment: Revisa las propiedades de la clase ImageStatic debe enviarte alguna ruta que puedas usar para renderizar la imagen, esa ruta la asignas al PictureBox con la propiedad ImageLocation